# How long should it take for a well pump to fill the tank after a power outage?

Tags: well-pump

Power out for 11 days. Just came back and well pump is running but no pressure inside house or outside. How long for 50 gallon tank to fill. will that give us pressure when tank is full?

Comment: Is pump primed? What is capacity in gpm of well, and pump?

Comment: If it is a pressurized bladder tank it will not fill all the way because of the bladder.it should have pressure right away even without the tank. The pump should provide the pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Is the pump a submersible type (pump down in the well) or a jet type pump with the motor and pump in the house or above the ground? If it an above ground pump, you probably need to prime the pump which means that you will need a pump guy shortly to fix an upcoming problem. If it is a submersible are you sure that the pump is running? The tank should fill in a couple minutes. The actual time depends on the size of the pump.

Answer (score 0):

I was called in a while back for a system with a submersible pump that was totally empty, the pressure tank had a good charge but the pump was shutting down, it was a deep well and the air pressure was filling the tank and shutting off the pump, all it took was opening the drain valve for 3 or 4 minutes until the water made it to the tank, then it filled and shut down normally, The home owner had not let the pump run for more than a minute because was worried about damaging the system. There may have been some crud stuck in the check valve that allowed the water to back flow but after getting water the pressure was solid. Note I have only seen this one time, If a jet pump d.George is right on the need to prime the pump I have had to do this many times.